# Displaying GPS longitude and latitude with java

Tags: java, gps

I want to read a stream of GPS data and display the latitude and longitude with java. If possible, I want a code snippet or class that does this.

Thanx :)

Comment: I'd like to make an air intake for a car. I'm not going to tell you which car, though. Is this possible?

Comment: In less sarcastic news, you need to actually show us what you've tried so far. This isn't a "give me teh codez" site. You need to do the research and work first. See the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Where is this "stream of GPS" coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RouteConverter](http://www.routeconverter.de/) is an application for dealing with GPS data in many different formats. There is a version without all the GUI stuff that can be used as an API.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a class that implements LocationListener and override onLocationChanged method.

It should be something similar to this.

```
public class abc implements LocationListener {
@override

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        if (location != null) {
        // This needs to stop getting the location data and save the battery power.
            locManager.removeUpdates(locListener); 
            String longitude = "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
            String latitude = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude();
        } 
    }
}
```